# Minor Annoyance: edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util

Tags: maven

I know this is trivial, but I bet I am not the only developer being annoyed by this issue:

I have a maven project building a Spring Hibernate frameowrk for a webapp.
I am building using Eclipse.

I use Eclipse shortcuts to import dependencies and often do so almost subconsciously.

Somewhere in my project dependencies I have a jar that includes the following package.

edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util

I often accidentally import this package instead of java.util and get compile or runtime errors.

QUESTION: How can I find out which dependency includes this package so I can (hopefully) exclude it using the Maven enforcer plugin.

Answer (score 7):

This does not directly answer your question but may help you prevent the accidental import in the first place:

In Eclipse you can add a *type filter* in *Preferences* → *Java* → *Appearance* → *Type Filters*.

From the description there:

> All types whose fully qualified name matches the selected filter strings will not be shown in the 'Open Type' dialog. They will also be ignored in content assist or quick fix proposals and when organizing imports. For example 'java.awt.*' will hide all types from the awt packages.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `mvn dependency:tree` from the command line. It will show a tree of your dependencies and their transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Within Eclipse you can open your `pom.xml` using the *Maven POM Editor* (default editor for POM files) and click on *Dependency Hierarchy*.

Within this view you can use a filter or select the dependency on the right side and the dependency tree for this dependency will be shown on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this issue with a Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA.

You can view transitive dependencies using the Maven command `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out where this package is creeping in.

However, it's worthwhile to mention that this problem can occur for Gradle or Maven projects. If you are using IntelliJ, then another workaround that will work for all of your projects - regardless of build tool - is to exclude the package altogether from the IDE's editor settings.

The steps to exclude the `edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util` package when using auto-import for all of your projects opened in IntelliJ are as follows (this is valid for IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (or click on File, then Settings)
- Editor > General > Auto Import
- Under the exclusion section, add the following exclusion with an IDE scope: `edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.*`

#### Reference Screenshot

[image: IntelliJ Auto Import Settings Dialog]